# Html oninvalid looping itself

Tags: html

I am  trying to set a custom validate message on my html form the message appears properly for the first but when i enter a value again  in the text box the message is still showing up blocking my submit

```
oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Plan for goals is required')"
```

Comment: Don't you need to manually set the setCustomValidity to the empty string again at some point?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz can't get u

Comment: If I go by the examples [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation), once you `setCustomValidity("Plan...")`, you've marked that field as invalid, until you `setCustomValidity("")` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `required` should be at the end of the input tag, here's how your code should look like :

```
<input type="number" min="30" max="300" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Plan for goals is required');" style="width:130px;" class="btn btn-default state" data-style="btn-default" ng-model="userlifestyle.goalSet.wkplans" ng-init="userlifestyle.goalSet.wkplans='@plannedWkDayForGoal'" required></input>
```

Comment: the type is number  and i don't want any pattern here

Comment: Hmm,okay. I just tried it with a number, and it works well. I'll see why you are getting that error.

Comment: <input type="number" min="30" max="300"  required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Plan for goals is required');"  style="width:130px;" class="btn btn-default state" data-style="btn-default"  ng-model="userlifestyle.goalSet.wkplans"  ng-init="userlifestyle.goalSet.wkplans='@plannedWkDayForGoal'"/> this is my complete input tag

Comment: Okay. Btw, I tried it out, Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dhruvramani/ga7ukgaq/